# Getting syntax error def receive(collection = [], fresh_packet, prefix = '')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting syntax error in the following code:

```
def (collection = [], fresh_packet, prefix = '')
end
```

If i reorder the arguments it works fine. I have not used splat but I don't what is going wrong with the parameters

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are passing in a required parameter `fresh_packet` in the middle of two optional parameters. Try this:

```
def receive(fresh_packet, collection = [], prefix = "")
end
```

In your own example Ruby has no way of knowing if the first argument you are passing is the optional or the required one. When you want to mix optional and required parameters, the required ones must come first. Check this blog post about [method arguments in Ruby](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/).

You can also pass in a hash instead:

```
def receive(options = {})
  fresh_packet = options[:fresh_packet]
  collection = options[:collection] || []
  prefix = options[:prefix] || ""
  # do stuff
end
```